# Using Media Querys with dynamic Properties in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

So one of my pages always has a Div with a Background Image which changes based on Media Querys (I fetch a smaller resolution from my CDN on Phone for example).

Now since I get the Image Url on Page Load I need to set it into CSS, this would be fine for a computed Style property but those don´t support Media Queries.

The only solution I saw yet was some Resize Event Listener but I would prefer to get a clean solution.

Example Code Snippet how it looks in CSS with a predefined Url:

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
  .image {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)), url("https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image/upload/c_scale,w_900/v.../3.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)), url("https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image/upload/c_scale,w_900/v.../3.jpg") no-repeat center;
      }
  }

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  .image {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)), url("https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image/upload/c_scale,w_1300/v.../3.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)), url("https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image/upload/c_scale,w_1300/v.../3.jp"") no-repeat center;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the VUE snippet that generates the image path?

Comment: @BryceHowitson I fetch the Post Document on Page load from my Database, there I have a field called "imgName", which looks like `house.jpg` then I simply bring that at the end of my CDN string and thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your assets included in the build output? If so you should let [Webpack deal with creating the paths](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html) instead of hardcoding them.

If that's not an option you can take a look at CSS `image-set` which is a way to define responsive images outside of media queries. However, [browser support isn't great](https://caniuse.com/#search=image-set).

Finally, you can use the `srcset` attribute in HTML and then hide/show the element based on media queries.

-- Edit:

I forgot that you can actually bind styles in the VUE.js template.
`v-bind:style` [Here's an example](https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-styles/). This is actually changing the style block that gets compiled on build. It's not an inline "computed" style.

-- Edit #2

Use VUE  to set a CSS Variable `--backgroundImage` this can then be used inside the media queries in your CSS. Someone made a great [Codepen](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/qrQGQQ) example.

CSS

```
:root {
  --backgroundImage: 'blank.png';
}

div {
  background-image: var(--backgroundImage);
}
```

VUE

```
watch: {
    img(val){
    element.style.setProperty('--backgroundImage', val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know of the Style bind but it doesn´t support Media Querys. No the Assets are from my CDN, I get the Image Path in the related Database Document that I fetch on Page load.

Comment: @Badgy I think I see the problem now. How about setting a CSS variable via VUE? Then you could use the CSS Variable inside the media queries but pass it from the script. [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/qrQGQQ) (not mine).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution that cross my mind is to save the windows width on page mount, and [add dynamically a class](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) according to the value.

```
data() {
   return {
      deviceWidth: 0
   }
}
```

Set the value on component mount hook

```
created() {
   this.deviceWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

And on you template

```
// handle extra sizes
<element 
   :class="{'image-ios': deviceWidth < 480, 'image-small': deviceWidth >= 480}"></element>
```

**Notice that you don't need a resizeListener because the resize is not going to happen in real life entering from a smartphone, so the width of the screen in the moment of mounting/creation will be enought**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) function to control the value you want to be applied. That way, all the browser engineers are optimizing the screen resize computation.

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, onUnmounted, onMounted} from "vue";

const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width : 480px)');
const isScreenLarge = ref(mediaQuery.matches)

const update = (event) => (isScreenLarge.value = event.matches);
onMounted(() => mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", update));
onUnmounted(() => mediaQuery.removeEventListener("change", update));

const background = computed(() => isScreenLarge.value ? 'large.jpg' : 'small.jpg';
</script>

<template>
<div>some content</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
div {
  background: v-bind(background);
}
</style>
```

You can even build a [composable](https://vueuse.org/core/useMediaQuery/) to do that in other parts of your app.